# ImportError: cannot import name pynestkernel

Tags: python, python-2.7, nest-simulator

So I spend last night trying to install nest (and pynest) to use with PyNN, and I am currently stuck. When I try to import nest I get:

```
>>> import nest
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nest/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from . import pynestkernel as _kernel
ImportError: cannot import name pynestkernel
```

However, when I make the make installcheck it passes all the pynest tests.
I am using OS x Yosemite, and I did a new install of python 2.7.9 using macport.

Tried:

```
easy_install python-nest
```

Now I am getting a new error.

Getting:

```
>>> import pyNN.nest as sim

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pyNN.nest as sim
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyNN/nest/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
from pyNN.nest import simulator
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyNN/nest/simulator.py", line 500, in <module>
state = _State()  # a Singleton, so only a single instance ever exists
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyNN/nest/simulator.py", line 60, in __init__
self._cache_num_processes = nest.GetKernelStatus()['num_processes'] # avoids blocking if only some nodes call num_processes
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'GetKernelStatus'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `setuptools` to install `nest` with `easy_install python-nest`.

Comment: easy_install installs only up to version 1.3. Nest is currently in version 2.6
Thanks for the suggestion nonetheless.

Comment: Then use `easy_install python-nest`

Comment: Tried that. Now I am getting a new error. Check question for details

Comment: Then run `easy_install PyNN` and `easy_install python-nest`.

Comment: At this point, I recommend installing the source and running through `python setup.py install`.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying something similar, with the further goal of having it working with python 3. So far I used the following commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/nest/nest-simulator.git
cd nest-simulator
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr/local/nest -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/python3 -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/include/python3.5m -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/libpython3.5.dylib .
make
make install
```

which runs without errors and I can happily run nest. Iam still having troubles running pyNN (see https://laurentperrinet.github.io/sciblog/posts/2016-06-01-compiling-and-using-pynn-%2B-nest-%2B-python3.html)